# Excel - If Table A1:A100 contains a value of A101:A200, then delete row

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office, office365

I have to admit, that I am fairly new to excel and this community.
However, I did try to program a makro what can manage **to delete rows in a specific range if a value below matches the one above.** (e.g. A1:A100 if it matches a value listet in A101:A200), because the "delete duplicates" tool doesn't seem to work.

Maybe you guys can give me a good answer / macro-code, which can perfon this kind of action.

greetings, valerius21

Comment: Am I reading this correctly...you are new to Excel and having trouble with the Remove Duplicates feature.  So you've decided to write a macro to replace it?  Remove Duplicates is a pretty stable feature.  Could you describe what Remove Duplicates isn't doing correctly?  Is there something odd in the nature of your data?  Hint: Spaces?

Comment: List 1: 001; 003; 011; 064; 092; 023; ..
List 2: 001; 002; 003; 004; 005; 006; ...

List 1 is only occupied at A, and List 2 occupies B to R as well as A.
And if a value of List 1 matches one of List 2, I want excel to delete the row

Comment: And they're all stored as text (leading zeroes suggest they are) with no extra spaces?  The number 3 is not the same as '003 to Excel.

Comment: they're just client numbers. so for ex. 12001 and 12122

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, your 1st comment substantively changes the question.  It's not that Remove Duplicates doesn't work - you're not actually trying to remove duplicate values - you're trying to remove items from one list where the Client ID is in the other list.

In a new column of the list you want to delete FROM, use the VLookup function to find matching values from the other list.  Then, use the Filter feature to find all of the matching value rows (the ones whose value you were able to successfully look up) and delete those.

Comment: VLookup Help:  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1